# Opening Activity in Background

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a question.

I am in my MainActivity and I want to open another activity in background and set text of textView which one is int this activity.

Should I use services or asyncTask to do it or can I do it in MainActivity?

Comment: Do you have any previous workings to what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it all in one activity. remember though, to update the ui, u must either us ASYNCTASK or a handler, a handler is easier, but ASYNCTASK is cleaner.  then simply launch the background activity as an intent, and you'll be good to go. another solution is to use a handler in the background activity, to  update the ui in your main activity

Answer (score 0):

You can start your activity with results and handle it after has terminated

[Getting a Result from an Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)